# WebSockets: отправить сообщение всем клиентам кроме отправителя

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket

Я разрабатываю чат на основе `WebSocket` и `WebRTC`.

Хотелось бы отправить сообщение всем подключенным пользователям, кроме отправителя, но я не могу найти подходящее решение. Точнее, я хотел бы посылать уведомления другим подключенных пользователям о том что новый пользователь присоединился к чату.

Сервер:

```
    // list of users
var CLIENTS=[];
var id = Math.random();

// web server is using 8081 port
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 });

// check if connection is established
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log('connection is established');

    CLIENTS[id] = ws;
    CLIENTS.push(ws);

    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        var received = JSON.parse(message);

         if(received.type == "login"){
            ws.send(message);  // send message to itself

               if(received.type == "login"){
                   ws.send(message);  // send message to itself
                     sendNotes(JSON.stringify({
                     user: received.name,
                     type: "notes"
               }), ws);

          }else if(received.type == "message"){
              sendAll(message); // broadcast messages to everyone including sender
          }

    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('user ' + CLIENTS[ws] + ' left chat');
        delete CLIENTS[ws];
    });

});

function sendNotes(message, ws) {
    if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws) {
        for (var i = 0; i < CLIENTS.length; i++) {
            CLIENTS[i].send(message);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('ELSE : ', message);
    }
}          

 function sendAll(message) {
        for (var i=0; i < CLIENTS.length; i++) {
        // Отправить сообщения всем, включая отправителя
            CLIENTS[i].send(message); 
        }
    }
```

Клиентская часть:

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    name = usernameInput.value;

    if(name.length > 0){
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: "login",
            name: name
        }));
    }

});

function sendData() {
    var data = dataChannelSend.value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('greetingUser').innerHTML;

    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        username : userName,  // fetch user name from browser, after login
        type : "message",
        message : data
    }));
}

socket.onmessage = function(message) {
    var envelope = JSON.parse(message.data);
    switch(envelope.type) {
        case "login":
            onLogin(envelope);
            break;
        case "message":
            showMessage(envelope);
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Получает ли каждый клиент какой-то уникальный id при коннекте? (можно попробовать его поискать в объекте ws). Если да, то можно попробовать пройтись циклом по всем клиентам (как вы делали в `sendAll`, но добавив дополнительную проверку `if (CLIENTS[i].id !== ws.id) { CLIENTS[i].send(message); }`. Если из коробки id нет, то можно подумать о создании своего id для текущего клиента на момент коннекта.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive т. е. написать так `var id = Math.random();  clients[id] = ws;` при коннекте  и после этого внутри функции `sendAll` добавить `if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws){ CLIENTS[id].send(message); }` ?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Добавил. Оповещения решил отправлять с помощью отдельной функции `sendNotes` , так аккуратнее. Дело в том что теперь, объект проходит через условие `if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws)` внутри функции sendNotes при первом логине, а по идее не должен был.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Добавил. Оповещения решил отправлять с помощью отдельной функции `sendNotes` , так аккуратнее. Дело в том что теперь, объект проходит через условие `if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws)` внутри функции `sendNotes` при первом логине, а по идее не должен был.

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan Вы, наверное, хотели обратиться к пользователю _Michael Radionov_, но почему-то случайно ссылались на меня в комментариях :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, спасибо :)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Добавил. Оповещения решил отправлять с помощью отдельной функции `sendNotes` , так аккуратнее. Дело в том что теперь, объект проходит через условие `if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws)` внутри функции `sendNotes` при первом логине, а другие пользователи нет, так не должно быть.